# Fedora 13 becomes unresponsive when too many applications running

Tags: linux, fedora

I am using Fedora 13 64bit on Dell Vostro full 4GB RAM system with default Gnome GUI.

This is very annoying problem that I don't how to fix except by rebooting the whole PC.

When I have too many applications running ( like browser windows), the system start acting sluggish. The fist symptoms appear in Eclipse IDE which becomes so terrible it just becomes frozen for sometime one whole minute after I try to edit something in the editor. Then Firefox seems like it has crashed. Google Chrome becomes very unresponsive as well. All GUI applications including File manager becomes unresponsive. 
When I check System Monitor, the CPU is still around 20% and memory is at 80% but the system seems getting fried up. This progressively becomes worse until I soft reboot it or if I dont do it evetually the whole system is fried, no response to any keyboard key or mouse and I have to hit the hardware turn off button.

I regularly yum update the system but this makes no difference.

Please don't tell not to run too many applications because I need those for my work. I thought Linux is well designed Operating System but I am very disappointed so far.

Can some one here help ?

Comment: What's the output of 'free' when this happens? What does 'top' show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Might be worth testing RAM and HDD? Sounds like it might a hardware fault. Drop to a terminal and run "top" and then press "P" to sort by CPU time to see which process is maxing the CPU(s) out.

Comment: There is no fault with RAM or HDD. The CPU time changes frequently for running processes. Mostly it is Chrome ( because I usually have many chrome windows open) or Eclipse java process etc.

Comment: What you are experiencing is certainly not typical behaviour for any Linux machine. You need to isolate the application which is causing the problem. For example, if the problem only exhibits with Chrome or Eclipse. If one process is hogging the CPU, other applications may also not respond, making it look as though that application is hanging. You could also try a different distribution. How have you tested RAM and HDD?

Comment: I have tested RAM and HDD, they are fine. I even took the system to repair center there is no hardware fault. If RAM was not good, then the system would suddenly crash or reboots itself segfaults etc but there is no such issue. The problem is that after I reboot, and start opening new browser windows or opening other applications over the course of 2 or 3 days, the system start becoming sluggish and unresponsive even though mememory usage is still below 90%. This progressivly becomes worse until the system does not respond to any keyboard key or mouse ( after about 10 days or so).

Comment: Can't be overheating problem as the system is well ventilated and its in cold room. I think it could because of some configuration settings that could fix this problem but I dont know how.

Comment: To confirm, 'top' reports that Chrome and Eclipse are using all the CPU? Are you running code when this happens? Is it a bug in your code?

Comment: Usually Chrome ( because I have sometime lot of windows open) and Eclipse tops the list for memory. CPU usage is usually around 15 to 50%. But this should not matter because even if memory was 100% it should swap to disk. No it has nothing to do with bug in my code.

Comment: Reinstall or try a different distribution or a different browser or a different version of Eclipse?